# np.linalg.inv still holds GIL? Use ThreadPoolExecutor with numpy matrix inverse

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy

I know that most of the numpy operations will release GIL. Therefore, most of them can get expected speed up when working with python's multithreading. But I found it weird that this is not the case with `numpy.linalg.inv`.

#### Experiment

I tried the following

```py
import numpy as np
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def numpy_op(arr):
    # do matrix inversion here
    return np.linalg.inv(arr)

num_workers = 8
np.random.seed(42)
args = [np.random.randn(10000, 10000) for _ in range(num_workers)]

# parallelize with thread pool
s_time = time.time()
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers) as executor:
    res = list(executor.map(numpy_op, args))

# sequential code
res = []
for arg in args:
    res.append(numpy_op(arg))
print(f'time consumed: {time.time()-s_time:.2f}s')
```

Results

- multithreading: 36.44s
- sequential: 28.14s

However, the speed up of multi-threading is quite normal if I do some other numpy operations other than matrix inversion, for example

```py
def numpy_op(arr):
    # some random numpy operations here
    return (arr**2 + 2) ** 0.5
```

With this operations, the results are

- multithreading: 0.62s
- sequential: 3.71s

### Version

I am using `Python 3.9.10` and `numpy 1.24.3`

Comment: To be clear ThreadPoolExecutor doesn't implement different CPU threads. It's concurrency within the same python process. I'm surprised by these results so there maybe something I don't know about C bindings like those used in numpy.  If you want multiple CPU threads: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the implementation of `np.linalg.inv` is itself multithreaded. To see this effect, add these lines to the top of your example:

```py
import os

os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
```

This reduces the number of threads available to such operations down to just one (assuming your numpy was built with openBLAS. See [threadpoolctl](https://github.com/joblib/threadpoolctl) for other cases.)

On my machine, this change flips the results:

- Sequential: 31.5 s -> 64.5 s
- Multithreaded: 56.0 s -> 26.8 s

I don't know if there is a comprehensive list of multithreaded operations in numpy, but it is something to consider when optimizing multicore throughput.